# directives, how to detect if it's fully rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

so i have a directive:

```
APP.directive('projectsStrip', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: 'ProjectCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/projects/projects.strip.html',
        link: function link($scope, elem, attrs) {
            $scope.$on('slides-ready', resizeStrip.bind(null, elem));
        }
    }
});
var resizeStrip = function(elem, ev, data){
    debugger;
};
```

and the template:

```
<div id="main" class="site-main">
    <div id="main-content" class="main-content">
        <div ng-repeat="slide in project.slides" class="post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-portfolio category-work tag-art tag-minimal tag-modern" style="width: 592px;">
            <img src="{{slide.url}}" alt="{{slide.title}}">
            <label>{{slide.label}}</label>
        <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the controller loads the projects, that come from anothe controller:

```
app.controller('ProjectCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.project = {};
    $scope.$on('project-selected', function(ev, project){
        $scope.project = project;
        $scope.$root.$broadcast('slides-ready');
    });
});
```

thing is, in the directive, when the function resizeStrip is ran, there is still no slides rendered in the html, so when i run `elem.find('img')` i get `[]`.
What is the proper way to tap into the moment the slides (`<div ng-repeat="slide in project.slides" ...>`) are rendered?

Comment: have you tried `$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() { }`?

Comment: You are triggering it far too early doing it in controller. Controller has to run before rendering can even start. Can use `$last` property of `ng-repeat` ... this won't assure that images themselves are loaded however

Answer (score 0):

When you broadcast `slides-ready` the `ngRepeat` directive still doesn't know that `project` has changed. The change hasn't been digested yet so nothing is rendered. You could wrap the broadcast into a `$timeout` call.

But even then you probably want to wait until the images are loaded. If so then you have to attach an `onLoad` event handler to the `img` elements. Only when all have been run you can call `resizeStrip`.